# Converting keyCode to key

Tags: javascript, keycode

I've been looking around and it seems that `String.fromCharCode()` is the method I was looking for, however, when trying to convert a keyCode using `String.fromCharCode()` the results are completely off

For example:

```js
let foo = 40;
console.log(String.fromCharCode(foo))
//Output "("
```

When at https://keycode.info `40` is `ArrowDown`, and also is `ArrowDown` when logging `event.key` as such:

```js
function logKey(event) {
    console.log(event.key);
    console.log("Key: " + event.keyCode)
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", logKey)
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String.fromCharCode issue for special characters in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768354/string-fromcharcode-issue-for-special-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: [Only if you've got the "key code" from a keypress event. In keyup and keydown events, the keyCode property has nothing to do with characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977792/how-to-convert-keycode-to-character-using-javascript#comment4255671_3977802)

Comment: Don't use `event.keyCode`. It is deprecated. It gives information about the keyboard "scan code", which does not necessarily have a relation with the key's name.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now, so there isn't any other method to convert back into a `key`?